# how to rotate pdf page and set origin

Tags: java, pdfbox

i'm trying to rotate every landscape page in document, so all pages are portrait orientation. i'm using apache pdfbox for that.

```
PDPage page = document.getPage(pageIndex);
PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
if(mediaBox.getWidth() > mediaBox.getHeight()) {
  page.setRotation(270);
}
```

this works fine, page is rotated. now, the problem is, that after i send document to printer, it will put some marks on it (see image1).

[image: printer marks on portrait (not rotated) page]

on rotated page however marks appear on wrong position. like it would appear on landscape page (see image2).

[image: printer marks on rotated page]

i think it has something to do with origin. do you have any ideas how to set origin, so that printer mark appears on right place?

thank you and best regards
Dalibor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);            int rotation = page.getRotation();
switch (rotation)
{
    case 90:
        width = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
        height = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
        cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), height, 0));
        break;
    case 180:
        cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(180), width, height));
        break;
    case 270:
        width = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
        height = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
        cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, width));
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

then continue with your stuff. Don't forget to close the content stream. The code above is taken from the `AddWatermarkText.java` example from the source code download.

Comment: Hi Tilman, thank you, that works like a charm. I'm wondering, why is the landscape page (which is landscape designed in Word and later converted to pdf) giving me rotation = 0? Best regards, Dalibor

Comment: Landscape is just a rectangle dimension. You can have a landscape page by using landscape rectangle dimension or by rotating a portrait page.